# Is it possible to read a JS file in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, file

So I'm working with a lot of JS files, split based on their function for easy maintenance and it's great... until I need to send the html file to someone

The best way to do that would be to put all the js into the html file to avoid issues, but then as there are a lot of file, it does take a little while to copy all of them and past into the html

Wondering if there is a way to read the js files and output them all as a string that I can put in a new js file

> A little example of the current code

```
var files = [
  "Physics.js",
  "renderer.js",
];

outputFilesAsText();

function outputFilesAsText(FilesSourceArray){
  Let array = FilesSourceArray;
  for(let i = 0; i < array.length; ++I){
    //Parse the js file to text and print it to the screen
  }
};
```

Comment: webpack, rollup, bower, ... . This isn't exactly what you want, as they use modules, but it's probably what you should use.

Comment: Typically there is some order required though, can all your files just be pasted together in any arbitrary order? If not, how do you define the order? Wouldn't modules and a dependency graph make things easier anyways?

Comment: @ASDFGerte Yeah, I'm not using them as module, just a s different js files in web

Comment: Oh, yes, they need to be ordered, but I actually just add one file to the HTML, that js file loads the other files with their sources in the array in the order they appear in the array

Comment: Well, if the filenames' order is known in some readable format (array here), you can probably write a tool that copies them together quite fast. Are they all in the same folder, or the paths included in that array? I'd still prefer modules and a bundler, but if you reject that, so be it. Do you know [`nodejs`](https://nodejs.org/en/)?

Comment: Oh, no, I'm using just regular JS
I don't know if JS files can be read the same way txt files